# how to find minimum value (excluding zeros) from multiple ranges of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, min

Thank you for reading my question. I am trying to find the minimum value of a few ranges of cells excluding zero. I know if it is a contiguous range that you can do small(countif(,0)+1). However, I am getting a #value error when I try to have multiple ranges. For example =SMALL((K32:K42,W32:W42,AI32:AI42,AU32:AU42),COUNTIF((K32:K42,W32:W42,AI32:AI42,AU32:AU42),0)+1). I am trying to find the minimum value of K32:K42,W32:W42,AI32:AI42,AU32:AU42. I appreciate any help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use CHOOSE in an IF to create an array and pass it to MIN:

```
=MIN(IF(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},K32:K42,W32:W42,AI32:AI42,AU32:AU42)>0,CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},K32:K42,W32:W42,AI32:AI42,AU32:AU42)))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or try this non-array formula proposal,

In `I11`, enter formula :

```
=1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},C2:C8,G2:G8,K2:K8,P2:P8),1)
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, AGGREGATE is an array formula, it is a native array formula so it does not require Ctrl-Shift-Enter, but still an array formula with all the other drawbacks.